# Hierarchical queries on Hive

Tags: hive, pyspark, hiveql

I have a data frame in pyspark with data like below

```
node 1: 
node 3:  1
node 5:  1
node 2:  3
node 4:  2
```

Now i need to know all the parents of node 4 , such that i get an output like

```
1,3,2
```

Is this possible using a Hive SQL query?

Comment: 4 is a parent of itself?

Comment: 4 is not a parent of itself. 4 has parent 2, 2 has parent 3, 3 has parent 1 and 1 is root node

Comment: "I need to know all the ***parents*** of node 4" => output: `1,2,3,4` implies `4` is a parent of 4.

Comment: ok.. 1,3,2 is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

SQL itself does not support iterations, nor recursion...

- with a `CONNECT BY` clause you could just let the database handle the recursion, and pretend it was easy >> not available in Hive
- with a procedural langage wrapper (e.g. T-SQL, PL/SQL, PgSQL) you could iterate until each leaf is connected to the root (...verbose code, no fun for testing...) >> not available in Hive either, unless you use **Python** to manage the iterations and run an INSERT query on each iteration, then collect the results